# Show distance to the half-space is equal to distance to the set

Tags: convex-optimization, projection

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex set, and $x^* \in C^c$ (not in $C$ and its closure).

Define the Euclidean distance from $x^*$ to $C$ as $d_C(x^*):=\min_{z \in C}\|z -x^*\|_2$.

Consider the closed half-space $H:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle a,x\rangle \leq \gamma \}$, where $a=x^*-\prod_C(x^*)$ and $\gamma=\langle a,\prod_C(x^*)\rangle$ where $\prod_C(x^*)$ is projection of $x^*$ onto $C$.

Show that $d_H(x^*)=d_C(x^*)$.

Intuitively, it says that the hyperplane defining in this way is tangent to the set $C$ at point $\prod_C(x^*)$.

[image]

Extension:

Show that the minimum distance from $x^*$ to $C$ is the maximum among the distance from $x^*$ to closed half-spaces $H$ containing $C$, i.e., $d_C(x^*)=\max_{C \subseteq H}d_H(x^*)$ where the max is taken over all closed half-spaces $H$'s containing $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Pi_C(x^\ast) \in C\subseteq H$, and $\Pi_H(x^\ast) \in H$. Then by construction of $H$,
$$0 \geq \langle x^\ast - \Pi_C(x^\ast),\Pi_H(x^\ast) - \Pi_C(x^\ast)\rangle = \langle \Pi_C(x^\ast) - x^\ast, \Pi_C(x^\ast) - \Pi_H(x^\ast) \rangle,$$
and by the variational inequality of Euclidean distance
$$0 \geq \langle x^\ast - \Pi_H(x^\ast),\Pi_C(x^\ast) - \Pi_H(x^\ast)\rangle.$$
So add the two inequalities together, and you should see that, in fact, $\Pi_C(x^\ast) = \Pi_H(x^\ast)$!

Comment: Oh boy. Perfect. Please keep answering. Can you look at the extension of the question?

Comment: Sure, but it seems that the community doesn't allow follow up questions to another question.(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers) Do you mind creating a separate question with your extension, and linking to this question?

Comment: I've provided a sketch that may be clear for the follow up here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014057/show-that-the-distance-of-x-ast-to-c-is-the-maximum-of-distances-from-x-a/3014058#3014058. Please comment in the link provided if it is not clear.

Comment: Can you help me for this question?

Comment: Could you help me to show this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023525/show-that-prod-kx-prod-kx-x-forall-x-in-mathbbrnwhere-k-i