# Show that the distance of $x^\ast$ to $C$ is the maximum of distances from $x^\ast$ to closed half-spaces $H\supseteq C$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

This Q&A is in response to the follow up question asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013392/show-distance-to-the-half-space-is-equal-to-distance-to-the-set).

Let $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex set, and $x^\ast \in C^c$. Define the Euclidean distance from $x^\ast$ to $C$ by $d_C(x^\ast) = ||x^\ast - \Pi_C(x^\ast)||_2 = \min_{z\in C}||x^\ast - z||_2$, where $\Pi_C(x^\ast)$ is the projection of $x^\ast$ onto $C$.

Show that the distance from $x^\ast$ to $C$ is the maximum among the distances from $x^\ast$ to closed half-spaces $H$ containing $C$, i.e., $d_C(x^\ast)=\max_{C\subseteq H}d_H(x^\ast)$, where the max is taken over all closed half-spaces $H$'s containing $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $d_C(x^\ast)\geq\max_{C\subseteq H}d_H(x^\ast)$ is trivial.

Note that it has been shown in the preceding question that $C\subseteq H_\ast \equiv \overline{H}^-(a,\gamma)$, where $H_\ast$ is a closed half space, $a = x^\ast - \Pi_C(x^\ast)$ and $\gamma = \langle x^\ast, \Pi_C(x^\ast) \rangle$, and in fact, $d_C(x^\ast) = d_{H_\ast}(x^\ast)$. Suppose $d_C(x^\ast)\not\leq\max_{C\subseteq H}d_H(x^\ast)$. Then $d_C(x^\ast)>\max_{C\subseteq H}d_H(x^\ast)$, and it's clear we have a contradiction.

Comment: Could you tell me why $d_C(x^\ast)\geq\max_{C\subseteq H}d_H(x^\ast)$ is trivial?

Comment: Do you agree that any closed half-space is convex? Then since for any closed half-space $H$ containing $C$, obviously $C\subseteq H$, even for the half-space $G$ containing $C$ such that $d_G(x^\ast) = \max_{C\subseteq H} d_H(x^\ast)$. Then since $G$ is a closed convex set, $||x^\ast - \Pi_G(x^\ast)||_2 = \min_{z\in G}||x^\ast - z||_2 \leq ||x^\ast - y||_2$ for all $y \in G$. Since $C\subseteq G$, $\Pi_C(x^\ast) \in G$. So $\Pi_C(x^\ast)$ is one such $y$.

Comment: @Intls, why is the convexity of the half-space necessary. $G$ being a superset of $C$ and there existing some point in $C$ such that its distance to $x^*$ is less than the distance from any point in $G$ to $x^*$ are contradictory statements.

Comment: @justaguy That's certainly true, but our definitions for Euclidean projection and Euclidean distance were only given for a closed convex set, so the convexity of the half-space was just to make sure everything was well-defined.