# Show that $\prod_K(x)+\prod_{-K^*}(x)=x$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$where $K$ is a cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $K^*$ be the dual cone of $K$, and $\prod_K(x)$ denote the Euclidean projection onto $K$.

Show that $\prod_K(x)+\prod_{-K^*}(x)=x$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This decomposition is called Moreau decomposition. Intuitive example is projection of a point onto the first and third quadrants because the first quadrant $K$ is a cone and its dual $K^*$ is itself so $-K^*$ is the third quadrant.

Comment: This is the Moreau conical decomposition. I believe you can find its proof in most of Convex Analysis textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following from characterization of projection holds for every $p \in K$

$$
\langle x-\Pi_K(x),p - \Pi_K(x) \rangle \leq 0
$$

$p=0 \in K$ so $
\langle x-\Pi_K(x), - \Pi_K(x) \rangle \leq 0
$

$p=\Pi_K(x) \in K$ then $2\Pi_K(x) \in K$ so VI $
\langle x-\Pi_K(x), \Pi_K(x) \rangle \leq 0
$

Hence, $$
\langle x-\Pi_K(x), \Pi_K(x) \rangle = 0
$$

what is left is to show $\Pi_{-K^*}=x-\Pi_K(x)$.

The point is ${-K^*}={K^{\circ}}$.

Claim: $z=x-\Pi_K(x)$ is in $K^{\circ}$.

$$
\langle x-\Pi_K(x),p - \Pi_K(x) \rangle \leq 0 \rightarrow \langle z,p - \Pi_K(x) \rangle = \langle z,p \rangle + \langle z,\Pi_K(x) \rangle = \langle z,p \rangle \leq 0
$$
$\Box$

For any $q$ in $K^{\circ}$ we have $\langle q, \Pi_K(x) \rangle \leq 0$. Because $
\langle z, \Pi_K(x) \rangle = 0
$, we have $\langle q, \Pi_K(x) \rangle - \langle z, \Pi_K(x) \rangle \leq 0$

Since $\Pi_K(x)=x-z$,

$$ \langle q- z, x-z \rangle \leq 0$$

The above inequality means $q=\Pi_{K^{\circ}}(x)$.